# Publishing site in Visual Studio 2005, without updating video files

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Is there a way to update and publish a site in Visual Studio 2005, without updating files that haven't changed.  I have a media folder that has videos and music.  I do not need to update this folder when we publish, it becomes a long process.  Instead I want to publish only the pages we have changed.  Is there a way, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the files and folder from the project.

They will still be on the file system, but will not get published with the rest of the site.

See [How to: Add and Remove Solution Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ee8zw5t%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (VS 2005) on MSDN.